# Растерянна или растеряна, уверенна или уверена?

Tags: орфография, нн, краткое-причастие, краткое-прилагательное

Вот цитата из книги:

*Она меня уже не пугает, как раньше. **И она явно растерянна**. Не понимает, что происходит* (Х. Вебб, 2019).

Я бы написала "**явно растеряна**". С другой стороны, это же прилагательное.

Но в словаре прилагательное имеет две формы письма. НН пишется, **если только**  *их лица растерянны*.

В Нацорпусе частотность 66:10 в пользу формы ***растеряна***, но используются они совершенно произвольно:

*Девочка **подавлена и растеряна**, но не хочет принимать помощь мачехи..*. [Альбина Локтионова.  «Психология на каждый день», 2011]

*Алла, бедная, **ужасно растерянна и подавленна**.*  [Ю. М. Нагибин. Дневник (1983)]

А теперь: ***уверена и уверенна.***

**Уверенный**; кр. ф. прич. -ен, -ена; кр. ф. прил. -ен, -ена (с дополн.: она уверена в своей правоте) и -ен, -енна (**без дополн.**: она спокойна и уверенна; движения её уверенны); будь уверена, будьте уверены (не сомневайся, не сомневайтесь). Получается, что **НН пишется чаще**, в том числе при **однородных** отношениях с прилагательным.

В Нацкорпусе частотность 4100:30 в пользу форму ***уверена***, но и эти 30 случаев используются неверно. Например: Теперь жду ответа, и я уверенна, что она скажет...

**Неладно что-то в датском королевстве с этой орфограммой...**

А вы как пишете эти слова?

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь:
В суффиксах страдательных причастий прошедшего времени пишется *нн*; как правило, эти причастия имеют **приставки** или пояснительные слова: *исправленная рукопись; правленные корректором гранки*.
При отсутствии приставок или пояснительных слов пишется одно *н*; ср.: *замощённые дороги — мощённые булыжником дороги — мощёные дороги*. В этом случае перед нами прилагательное, образованное от страдательного причастия прошедшего времени: *правленый текст, бешеный волк, вяленая вобла, глаженые брюки, драная куртка, золочёные изделия, ломаная линия, путаный ответ, рваная рана, сеяные травы, стираное бельё* и т. п.
С краткими формами наоборот:
В кратких формах страдательных причастий пишется одно *н*. В кратких отглагольных прилагательных (как и в отыменных) сохраняется написание *нн*. **Отглагольные прилагательные отвечают на вопрос «каков?» («какова?», «каково?», «каковы?»)**.

Приставки подсознательно способствуют тому, чтобы написать с одной *н*, даже если есть качество. Протягивание звука *н* при наличии приставки не сильно звучит. Поэтому такая частотность. Если значение качества крайне велико, то протягивание звучит: *Она очень растерянна сама по себе. Она очень уверенна по жизни.*

Важным фактором является наличие наречия перед словом. Обратим внимание на пример с "ужасно".

Comment: oleedd, вы вопрос поняли? Тогда для чего вы мне всё это рассказываете? У нас другая проблема. Есть два конкретных прилагательных (не причастия!), которые могут писаться с Н и НН.  В словаре названы условия выбора Н и НН для каждого из них. Получается, что  первое предложение (в вопросе) написано неверно. А в Нацкорпусе полно неправильных предложений. Многие пользователи с этой информацией незнакомы. Это что теперь, словарные слова? Или правило какое есть? И не надо придумывать предложения (ведь знаете об этом). Правильно: она  очень растеряна, но она спокойна и уверенна. Почему?

Comment: Почему "она очень растеряна"? Не согласен.

Comment: Словарь почитайте. РАСТЕРЯННЫЙ; кр. ф. прич. -ян, -яна; кр. ф. прил. -ян, -яна (утративший способность соображать, растерявшийся) и -ян, -янна (выражающий растерянность: их лица растерянны)

Comment: С "очень" точно будет *нн*. Вот это первое ("растерявшийся") тут не подходит. Почему-то Кузнецов и Ефремова вывели это второе значение. У Ушакова и Ожегова его нет. Следует различать: *растеряна от чего-то* (временно) и *растерянна по характеру* (как качество личности).

Comment: Про Ушакова и Ожегова  забудьте. Электронный «Орфографический академический ресурс АКАДЕМОС» Института русского языка им. В.В. Виноградова РАН является официальной публикацией. Пополняется каждый год.

Comment: Не стоит воспринимать орфографический словарь как что-то незыблемое. В этом, возможно, самом сложном орфографическом правиле могут быть неточности. "*В АКАДЕМОС исправлены ошибки, обнаруженные со времени выхода словаря*" — кто его знает, какие ещё есть ошибки.

Comment: Какие ошибки? Словарь - это норма, в отличие от Правил, его даже утверждать нигде не нужно. Как скажут, так и будете писать. Только вот "она очень растеряна" я бы тоже написала с одной Н. Форма "растерянна" редко используется, даже для глаз непривычна.

Comment: Но если её и использовать, то именно в таких случаях. Когда же ещё (если речь о человеке)? Это та тема, в которой споры имеют место даже при составлении словаря.

Comment: Не знаю. Я просто обратила внимание на эти словарные статьи, не более того. Спасибо за беседу.